# Django order by number of related objects in class Meta

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, i want to set the default model ordering to be by the number of related objects. In my case i would like to order the objects by the number of likes, where likes is a `ManyToManyField` of users that have liked the post:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class Meta:
        ordering = []  # What can i put here?
```

The common solution seems to be [django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```py
from django.db.models import Count

top_posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes')).order_by('-num_likes')
```

But this is called on the queryset, and doesn't seem like an option when defining the model.
I also read about [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/expressions/), where the `F` expression seems like it may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the best way is to work with a manager in this case:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .alias(num_likes=Count('likes'))
            .order_by('-num_likes')
        )


class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    objects = PostManager()
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping it could be done to the actual model, as it seems more readable to me, but if not i will use this! Thanks

Comment: @DNIIBOY: well perhaps by constructing a custom lookup that would thus make a subquery, but with the tools "available", likely not: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-lookups/